# multiple organizations/accounts and dev environments for S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, continuous-integration

As per best practice aws resources should be per account (prod, stage, ...) and its also good to give devs their own accounts with defined limits (budget, region, ...).

Im now wondering how i can create a `full working dev environment` especially when it comes to `S3 buckets`.

Most of the services are pay per use so its totally fine to spin up some lambdas, SQS etc. to use the real services for dev.

Now to the real questions what should be done with `static assets` like pictures, downloads and so on which are stored in S3 buckets?

**Duplicating those buckets for every dev/environment could come expensive as you pay for storage and/or data transfer.**

What i thought was to give the devs S3 bucket a redirect rule and when a file is not found (e.g. 404) in the dev bucket it redirects to the prod bucket so that images, ... are retrieved from there.

I have testet this and it works pretty well but it solves only part of the problem.

**The other part is how to replace those files in a convenient way?**

Currently static assets and downloads are also in our git (maybe not the best idea after all ... - how you handle file changes which should go live with new features, currently its convenient to have it in git as well) and when someone changes stuff they push it and it gets deployed to prod.

**We could of course sync back the devs S3 bucket to prod bucket with the new files uploaded but how to combine this with merge requests and have a good CI/CD experience?**

**What are your solutions to have S3 buckets for every dev so that they can spinn up their own completely working dev environment with everything available to them?**

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that you don't want to complicate things just to save a few dollars. S3 costs are pretty cheap, so if you're just talking about website assets, like HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and some images, then you're probably going to spend more time creating, managing, and troubleshooting a solution than you'll save. Time is, after all, your most precious resource.

If you do have large items that need to be stored to make your system work then maybe have the S3 bucket have a lifecycle policy on those large items and delete them after some reasonable amount of time. If/when a dev needs that object they can retrieve it again from its source and upload it again, manually. You could write a script to do that pretty easily.